Android Studio and Google maps api Style maps, how to change country color on map click
I have created a styled map in Google Maps console, customized it to show only countries and cities.
map style
I have implemented the click listener:


@Override
public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
    
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        Toast.makeText(this, country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch (NullPointerException np){
        //todo
    }

I need to change the color of this coutry. I found no documentation for that feature, is this doable?
At this point i am just printing the name of the country and it works. I cannot find documentation about the feature in mind. I saw that this feature (data-driven styling) might be not supported in Android?


Check this question.
Another way is you can use cloud based maps styling.


Cloud based maps styling IS what i am using.
